# Using interface correct in java

Tags: java, interface, default-value

Having this interface

```
public interface BookService {

List<Book> search(int childLimitPages, int numberOfBooks, List<Book> sourceOneResultSet, List<Book> sourceTwoResultSet);
}
```

Having 2 implementations when one does not use variable **int childLimitPages** in its implementation.

```
 public class AdultBookList implements BookService {

 // This won't work since there is missing variable, I am asking if there is other way to provide this ask
     List<Book> search(int numberOfBooks, List<Book> sourceOneResultSet, List<Book> sourceTwoResultSet) {
       .....
     }
 }

 public class ChildrenBookList implements BookService {

     List<Book> search(int childLimitPages, int numberOfBooks, List<Book> sourceOneResultSet, List<Book> sourceTwoResultSet) {
       .....
     }
 }
```

My question how should I use it? Should I have 2 interface? Could I have default variable?

Answer (score 3):

When you implement an interface you need to define all methods with exactly the same signature declared in the interface.

So the class

```
    public class AdultBookList implements BookService {

         List<Book> search(int numberOfBooks, 
                           List<Book> sourceOneResultSet, 
                           List<Book> sourceTwoResultSet) {
       .....
     }
 }
```

is not a valid implementation of the interface `BookService` because the method search has a different signature.

You can solve it in different ways.

First way is to overload the method search in the interface and provide also the method without the childLimitPages parameter. In the implementations you can throw an exception in the AdultBookList if you are calling the method with the childLimitPages. But I suggest you a more elegant way to solve it in the second way.

Second way is to replace all the parameters with an object wrapping them. In this object you can define default values, so when it is not explicitly set the value it takes the default value, so something like:

```
public interface BookService {
    List<Book> search(SearchRequest request);
}

...
public class SearchRequest {
    // I replaced int with Integer to hold also null values
    private Integer childLimitPages;

    // Defining a default value
    private int numberOfBooks = 10;
    private List<Book> sourceOneResultSet;
    private List<Book> sourceTwoResultSet;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Sure I know. I'm asking if there other way to provide this ask.

Comment: @userit1985 check the updated answer please

Answer (score 0):

You could define the first argument as `Optional<Integer>` and assert that in the AdultBookService the value in the Optional is present.

```
public interface BookService {
    List<Book> search(Optional<Integer> limit, int numberOfBooks, List<Book> sourceA, List<Book> sourceB);
}

public class AdultBookList implements BookService {

    List<Book> search(Optional<Integer> limit, int numberOfBooks, List<Book> sourceA, List<Book> sourceB) {
    }
}

public class ChildrenBookList implements BookService {

    List<Book> search(Optional<Integer> childLimitPages, int numberOfBooks, List<Book> sourceA, List<Book> sourceB) {
    }
}
```

I like my APIs to have optional arguments at the end. And to redirect the calls to an internal computation where the optionals are resolved. Like so:

```
public class AdultBookList implements BookService {

    List<Book> search(int numberOfBooks, List<Book> sourceA, List<Book> sourceB, Optional<Integer> limit) {
        if (limit.isEmpty())
        {
            System.err.printf("The limit should have been set!");
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        return internalSearch(numberOfBooks, sourceA, sourceB, limit.get());
    }

    private List<Book> search(int numberOfBooks, List<Book> sourceA, List<Book> sourceB, int limit) {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define multiple methods on your interface.

You have two different behaviors, so you must offer two different methods. Instead of one `search` method, offer `searchForPageCount` and `searchByNumberOfBooks`.

```java
public interface BookService {

    List<Book> searchForPageCount ( int childLimitPages, int numberOfBooks, List<Book> sourceOneResultSet, List<Book> sourceTwoResultSet ) ;

    List<Book> searchByNumberOfBooks ( int numberOfBooks, List<Book> sourceOneResultSet, List<Book> sourceTwoResultSet ) ;

}
```